# Scrapy spider get information that is inside of links

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have done and spider that can take the information of this [page](http://guia.bcn.cat/index.php?pg=search&q=%2a%3a%2a) and it can follow "Next page" links. Now, the spider just takes the information that i'm showing in the following structure.

The structure of the page is something like this

```
Title 1
URL 1 ---------> If you click you go to one page with more information
Location 1

Title 2
URL 2 ---------> If you click you go to one page with more information
Location 2

Next page
```

Then, that i want is that the spider goes on each URL link and get full information. I suppose that i must generate another rule that specify that i want do something like this.

The behaviour of the spider it should be:

1. Go to URL1 (get info)
2. Go to URL2 (get info)
3. ...
4. Next page

But i don't know how i can implement it. Can someone guide me?

Code of my Spider:

```
class BcnSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'bcn'
allowed_domains = ['guia.bcn.cat']
start_urls = ['http://guia.bcn.cat/index.php?pg=search&q=*:*']

rules = (
    Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(
            allow=(re.escape("index.php")),
            restrict_xpaths=("//div[@class='paginador']")),
        callback="parse_item",
        follow=True),
)

def parse_item(self, response):
    self.log("parse_item")
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath("//div[@id='llista-resultats']/div")
    items = []
    cont = 0
    for site in sites:
        item = BcnItem()
        item['id'] = cont
        item['title'] = u''.join(site.xpath('h3/a/text()').extract())
        item['url'] = u''.join(site.xpath('h3/a/@href').extract())
        item['when'] = u''.join(site.xpath('div[@class="dades"]/dl/dd[1]/text()').extract())
        item['where'] = u''.join(site.xpath('div[@class="dades"]/dl/dd[2]/span/a/text()').extract())
        item['street'] = u''.join(site.xpath('div[@class="dades"]/dl/dd[3]/span/text()').extract())
        item['phone'] = u''.join(site.xpath('div[@class="dades"]/dl/dd[4]/text()').extract())
        items.append(item)
        cont = cont + 1
    return items
```

**EDIT** After searching in internet I found a code with which i can do that.

First of all, I have to get all the links, then I have to call another parse method.

```
def parse(self, response):
    #Get all URL's

    yield Request( url= _url, callback=self.parse_details )

def parse_details(self, response):
    #Detailed information of each page
```

If you want use Rules because the page have a paginator, you should change `def parse` to `def parse_start_url` and then call this method through Rule. With this changes you make sure that the parser begins at the `parse_start_url` and the code it would be something like this:

```
rules = (
    Rule(
        SgmlLinkExtractor(
            allow=(re.escape("index.php")),
        restrict_xpaths=("//div[@class='paginador']")),
        callback="parse_start_url",
        follow=True),
)

def parse_start_url(self, response):
    #Get all URL's

    yield Request( url= _url, callback=self.parse_details )

def parse_details(self, response):
    #Detailed information of each page
```

Thant's all folks

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way of achieving this. Click next on your link, and read the new url carefully:

```
http://guia.bcn.cat/index.php?pg=search&from=10&q=*:*&nr=10
```

By looking at the get data in the url (everything after the questionmark), and a bit of testing, we find that these mean

- `from=10` - Starting index
- `q=*:*` - Search query
- `nr=10` - Number of items to display

This is how I would've done it:

- Set `nr=100` or higher. (1000 may do as well, just be sure that there is no timeout)
- Loop from `from=0` to 34300. This is above the number of entries currently. You may want to extract this value first.

Example code:

```
entries = 34246
step = 100
stop = entries - entries % step + step

for x in xrange(0, stop, step):
    url = 'http://guia.bcn.cat/index.php?pg=search&from={}&q=*:*&nr={}'.format(x, step)
    # Loop over all entries, and open links if needed
```

Comment: That i have to do it's get all urls (that i have in `item['url']`) and then use this list like a start_urls[URL_LIST]? Or i can do all the steps directly using this loop?

Comment: @CarlosEspeleta You have to extract all links from each page. For each iteration in the for loop, extract all 100 urls, and do whatever you want with them

Comment: Ok, i already have the links but how i can open them? Thanks for your time